# how should the program get text from user?

Tags: java, user-interface, jpanel

In order to get the text input from user in a new window what should I do?
I know that a text-field can do that. But I don't know how to add a text field in a new window that after input the data and  press a "ok" button, the window close.

Comment: Are you asking about [dialog boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)?

Comment: yes sth like that if I can add a text-field to it.

Comment: Take a look at [JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) and [JTextPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JOptionPane can be used for user input if you want to keep it really simple.
Short example:

```
String userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input your text.");
```